# WSO2 identity server - question for mfa for RDP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we are new  to identity management
and testing  wso2

is there a plugin or way to  use  WSo2  in premise idenity server and   MFA  for  various  RDP servers  logins?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no documented way to implement SSO for RDP servers with the WSO2 Identity Server.